# Pandas.read_json(JSON_URL)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using Pandas to get data from an API. The API returns data in JSON format. However the json has some values that I don't want in the dataframe. Because of these values, I am not able to assign an index to data frame. Following is the format.

```
{
"Success": true,
"message": "",
"result": [{"id":12312312, "TimeStamp":"2017-10-04T17:39:53.92","Quantity":3.03046306,},{"id": 2342344, "TimeStamp":"2017-10-04T17:39:53.92","Quantity":3.03046306,}]}
```

I am only interested in the "result" part. 
One way to do this is to import json with `request.get(request_URL)` and then after extracting the "result" part, convert the result into the dataframe.
2nd way can be to import the data with `Pandas.read_json(JSON_URL)` convert the returning dataframe back to a json, then after extracting "result" part, convert the result into the dataframe.

Is there any other way to do this? What is the best approach and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(json['result'])
print (df)

   Quantity               TimeStamp        id
0  3.030463  2017-10-04T17:39:53.92  12312312
1  3.030463  2017-10-04T17:39:53.92   2342344
```

Also here working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['result'])
print (df)
   Quantity               TimeStamp        id
0  3.030463  2017-10-04T17:39:53.92  12312312
1  3.030463  2017-10-04T17:39:53.92   2342344
```

For `DatetimeIndex` convert column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')
print (df)

                         Quantity        id
TimeStamp                                  
2017-10-04 17:39:53.920  3.030463  12312312
2017-10-04 17:39:53.920  3.030463   2342344
```

EDIT:

Solution with load data:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd

response = urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-ETC")
json_data = response.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace')

d = json.loads(json_data)
df = pd.json_normalize(d['result'])
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')

print (df.head())
                          Quantity     Total  
TimeStamp                                     
2017-10-05 06:05:06.510   3.579201  0.010000  
2017-10-05 06:04:34.060  45.614760  0.127444  
2017-10-05 06:04:34.060   5.649898  0.015785  
2017-10-05 06:04:34.060   1.769847  0.004945  
2017-10-05 06:02:25.063   0.250000  0.000698
```

Another solution:

```
df = pd.read_json('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-ETC')
df = pd.DataFrame(df['result'].values.tolist())
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')
print (df.head())

                          Quantity     Total  
TimeStamp                                     
2017-10-05 06:11:25.100   5.620957  0.015704  
2017-10-05 06:11:11.427  22.853546  0.063851  
2017-10-05 06:10:30.600   6.999213  0.019555  
2017-10-05 06:10:29.163  20.000000  0.055878  
2017-10-05 06:10:29.163   0.806039  0.002252
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, how can I make TimeStamp the index.

Comment: So some thing strange is happening I am using the pd.DataFrame(d['result'])  get the data frame, however it only returns a single column buy the name of "result". https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-ETC is where the data is coming from . Appreciate the help.

Comment: I think first solution is more general, the best use it. `df = json_normalize(json['result'])`

Comment: I add 2 possible solutions, please check edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, based on jezrael's using requests:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

d = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkethistory?market=BTC-ETC").json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['result'])
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')

df
```

Comment: What if the json data from the "get" request is too large, is that handled easily. or is there some other better approach?