# Python Django API authentication

Tags: python, django, postman

I am new to Django. I need to use some API to get the .json format data. But the API needs authentication. I have already got the username and password. I see my colleague use Postman to enter the account then he can see the JSON file in intellij.

I am in Pycharm, I am wondering is there some code I can use to realize the same function of postman rather than install the postman?
What I have: API URL, account username and password

Any help is really appreciated, also please let me know which file I should write in the Django, views.py??

---

Update: thank you for all the help！I am sorry I am not familiar with the postman, I only know my colleague show me how to enter the username and password.

I have the API/URL, when I click on it, it will direct me to a page with JSON format data, looks like this

```
{"businessOutcomes":[{"businessOutcomeId":"1234","origin":"JIRA",.....]}
```

I have over 100 this kind of URL/API, I want to get the .json file in pycharm and so I can make them as the df to do the data analysis I want.
And my colleague told me that the API has some authentication and I have to use the username and password to get in.

I hope this explain what I want to realize.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to do but it is easy to create a REST API with json output using Django REST Framework.

Comment: use of PostMan is for Testing Purpose to check yours API is working fine or not. but as a final step you have to use it using `requests` module if you're calling it from `python`. or use of `Ajax or Axios` which are based on Javascript. the you have to include your `creds` as `payload` and then you will response based on your `API`.

Comment: If you are just looking to test the api, if you are using PyCharm professional, and an hour or so to learn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwiHAukbWjM&ab_channel=IntelliJIDEAbyJetBrains

Comment: @AMG Hi AMG, thank you for the help. I am in the community version of Pycharm.....and I do some detailed info in the original question.

Comment: Get your json data into a response object, then read it with panda's read_json. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46578150/4872140 for a sample. How you use the user/pass depends on the type of authentication. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65222521/4872140